# Getting server error when redirecting to thankyou page using phpmailer with smtp

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

Working within the Canvas HTML5 template.  That particular template used an inline success message once an email had been sent through a form on the page.  I had to switch the setup to use SMTP and redirect to a thank you page.  The emails are coming through, but it's not redirecting me once the mail is sent.  Instead I get an Internal Server Error.  Is my syntax just off?  I don't have access to the back-end other than FTP.

The emails are coming through.  It's just the redirect that seems to be off.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
                'email' => 'recipient@domain.com', // Your Email Address
                'name' => 'Recipient Name' // Your Name
            );


$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Username = "forms@domain.com";
$mail->Password = "PaSsWoRd";


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

        $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
        $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
        $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
        $company = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-company'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-company'] : '';
        $subject = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] : '';
        $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
                $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
            }
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $company = isset($company) ? "Firm or Company Name: $company<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: \n$message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $company $message $referrer";



            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
//ORIGINAL ECHO OF SUCCESS MESSAGE              
//echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
//SWITCH TO REDIRECT
header("Location: ../thank-you.php");
            else:
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

The Form:

```
<form class="nobottommargin" id="template-contactform" name="template-contactform" action="php/sendemail.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-process"></div>

    <div class="col_half">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="template-contactform-name" value="" class="sm-form-control border-form-control required" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="col_half col_last">
        <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="template-contactform-email" value="" class="required email sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>

    <div class="col_half">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-phone" name="template-contactform-phone" value="" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="Phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="col_half col_last">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-company" name="template-contactform-company" value="" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="Company Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col_full">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-subject" name="template-contactform-subject" value="" class="sm-form-control border-form-control" placeholder="Subject" />
    </div>

    <div class="col_full">
        <textarea class="sm-form-control border-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="template-contactform-message" rows="7" cols="30" placeholder="What do you think we should know?"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col_full">
        <button class="button button-black noleftmargin topmargin-sm" type="submit" id="template-contactform-submit" name="template-contactform-submit" value="submit">Send Message</button>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="col_full hidden">
        <input type="text" id="template-contactform-botcheck" name="template-contactform-botcheck" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Check your server's error logs for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I don't have access, else I would have =/

Comment: is thank-you.php where you are looking for it? have you tried redirecting to something like google.com to check that the redirect is working at all?

Comment: Without that information you're only going to be able to guess at what is causing the problem.

Comment: @brad - Good suggestion.  Switched to header("Location: http://www.google.com"); //stack turned that into a link.  Used the full http address.

Still getting same error

Comment: header redirects could possibly be disabled on the server. Unfortunately I believe you might have to contact the person(s) responsible for server and get logs and/or  ask about redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone in the future, in this particular instance, I believe phpMailer was sending the headers more than once which was causing conflicts on the server.

The fix was to buffer the output until the entire process had finished and then send everything at once.  This was done using `ob_start();` at the beginning of the "action" php file referenced in the html form (just after "`<?`") and then `ob_end_flush();` at the end of that file (just before "`?>`").

Someone may correct me (I'm clearly not a PHP expert), but as I understand it, this holds all of the header info in a buffer and then sends at once rather than trying to send header info more than once.

Regardless if that's the correct way to explain it, the solution worked and the page redirects to the thank you page as intended.  If anyone has a better explanation, feel free to write it up and I'm happy to accept someone else's answer.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement syntax is off. Either use the curly brackets or this form $var==TRUE ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'; // get TRUE

Additional help here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

and here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

As per your request, run this first to make sure it is the if syntax.

```
if( $sendEmail == true )
     {
     header("Location: ../thank-you.php");
     }
    else { }
```

Could also be $sendEmail is not true.  Mail can return an error https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php

Comment: I was thinking this syntax was off.  Would it be too much to ask you to show me that full line in the proper syntax with the curly brackets?  I don't want to take advantage of you, but I'm hacking my way through PHP and I'll spend 10x as long getting it right =/.   Sincerely appreciated either way.

Comment: I added a snip for you to try in my answer.  Add the additional conditional statements if that runs.

Comment: Vague feedback from hosting IT dept:  

"It may just be the case that the headers have already been sent before the call was made. In this case, I would recommend making the redirect call as high up in the code as possible, or alternatively turning on output buffering to stop the headers from being sent before his call. 
 
The redirect directive should always be one of the first things in the buffer, if there is anything that could potentially display to the user before this call is made, it’s likely it won’t work.

Comment: So enclosing the whole thing using the output buffer worked.  I simply used ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); and the redirect went through as intended.